# Maven: Where be the code?

Tags: java, maven-2

Greetings,

Can anyone tell me how the heck I'm meant to use a maven repository or whatever the term is with a project?

I've downloaded the OAuth library from Google. I run mvn compile, test, install, deploy

I want to know where the Jar goes so I can just put it into my class path. Any help appreciated!

Comment: are you trying to determine where your code is or where the oauth code goes (i answered the latter question below)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me how the heck I'm meant to use a maven repository or whatever the term is with a project? I've downloaded the OAuth library from Google (...) I want to know where the Jar goes so I can just put it into my class path. Any help appreciated!

Basically, what you need to do with Maven to *"put a library on the class path"* is to **declare** this library as a dependency of a Maven project. Let's see how to do this and how to get started here.

First, you need to create a Maven project (i.e. a directory containing a `pom.xml` used to **describe** your project and following a given structure). Maven provides a tool that can create a project for you, you just have to run the following command (where the `artifactId` is the name of your project):

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow -DartifactId=Q2722892 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Then `cd` in to the project directory and edit the `pom.xml` to **declare** the oauth repository (Maven has a [**central remote repository**](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) called *central* which is known by default but oauth is not available in central so you need to tell Maven where to find it):

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>oauth.googlecode.com</id>
      <url>http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Now you can **declare** a dependency on the `aouth` artifact (or whatever artifact you want to get from the oauth repository):

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.oauth.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth</artifactId>
      <version>20090825</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now you can use the oauth library in the code under `src/main/java`, the oauth library is on the class path.

To build your project, run `install` (this will do a bit more than compiling, running tests, packaging but this is my recommendation):

```
mvn install
```

And find the jar of your project under the `target` directory.

To be honest, this particular example is not the easiest one to get started with Maven because it requires to understand several concepts that can't be covered in a single answer and I would warmly recommend to check [Maven by Example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html) for a good introduction of Maven before to go further.

Comment: Thanks -  don't like Maven! I can appreciate why it might be useful for some. I rather just dump my JAR's into one directory. Curse Apache :)

Comment: @steve Hmm... what about don't use Maven then? :?

Comment: Droids (And Mahout) seem to be using it. I'm sure this is something that will grow on me! Can you please add this to your answer - 

<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
    <archive>
     <manifest>
      <mainClass>im.jeanfrancois.App</mainClass>
     </manifest>
    </archive>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>

Answer (score 6):

The jar exists within the $MAVEN_PROJECT/target folder.

A copy also gets put into your local repository at $HOME/.m2/repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven to build your project, you just have to add the jar as a dependency in your POM.xml. maven will automatically look in the local (.m2/repository) repository for all dependencies. If it doesnt find it, it tries downloading from *central* (maven's default online rep) or any other repository you have specified.
You wouldnt need to add anything to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Should be under your HOME_DIRECTORY/.m2/repository. Look at the settings.xml file under .m2 folder. There should be a tag like this:

```
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

That says where the jars get stored. HTH

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you mean "where do i put the oath library?") It appears that that project has a [repository](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven/) already.  you can stick this in a repositories section in your project's pom.xml.